# How do I show the direction angle of a vector in 3d space?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

Given a vector $P$ in $3\text D$ space, I understand that the rotation matrices around:

the $x$-axis ($yz$ plane) would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0  & \cosα &  \sinα\\ 0 & -\sinα  & \cosα\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z' \end{pmatrix}$$

the $y$-axis ($xz$ plane) would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha&0&-\sin \alpha\\ 0  &1 & 0\\ \sin \alpha & 0  & \cosα\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z' \end{pmatrix}$$

the $z$-axis ($xy$ plane) would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha&\sin \alpha&0\\ -\sin \alpha  & \cosα &  0\\ 0 & 0  & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z' \end{pmatrix}$$

I however cannot understand neither can I correctly visualize the exact position of the direction angle $α$ (see diagram) in $3\text D$ space.

[image]

**N/B:** I have drawn (see diagram) the rotation around the $y$-axis to show the illustration of the math.

[image]

Comment: $\alpha$ is three different angles. In your first formula, it is an anticlockwise rotation by $\alpha$ in the (y, z) plane. In the second the rotation is in the (x, z) plane and in the third it is in the (x, y) plane.

Comment: @Paul: your comment is fully right, only that he is using a *clockwise* rotation moving from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x',y',z')$

Comment: Most often one uses the "direction cosines".  They are the cosines of the angles the vector makes with the positive x-axis, the positive y-axis, and the positive z-axis.   You don't have to actually find those angles- the "direction cosines" of a vector are simply the x, y, and z components of the unit vector in that direction.

Comment: Specifying the direction of a vector in space (like in your first figure) and specifying a three-dimensional rotation are two quite different things. I don't know if we can give you an answer that will actually help you. Perhaps it would be better if you explained more about where you got this angle $\alpha$ and what you need to do with it.

Comment: Thank you @DavidK. I have an algorithm that will require fitting planes using sets of `3d` coordinates computed from various locations of a matrix. In `2d`, the algorithm struggles to fit horizontal/vertical lines, hence, I applied a rotation (similar to my 2nd diagram) which initially deviates the horizontal/vertical lines to angle `(α)`, fits the lines, then transforms them back to their original position. Note that in the `2d` part, `α` was estimated from an already computed `(x,y)` coordinate using another method entirely (i.e. without fitting lines) such that:  `α = tan-1(y/x)`

Comment: Now I am trying to replicate this idea in `3d`, but I am not sure how to compute `α` for each plane - giving the already known `(x,y,z)` coordinate as in `2d`. I don’t know if this makes sense?

Comment: Thank you @Paul. So if i get you correctly, are you saying that `α` will be: `tan-1(z/y)`, `tan-1(x/z)`, `tan-1(y/x)` for the `YZ`, `XZ`, and `XY` planes, respectively?

Comment: You might need to start a new question explaining exactly what you want as people (including me) will not want to read through the comments. It seems quite different from where you started here.

Comment: If the idea is that the data are clustered around a plane $\Pi$ and you are trying to guess the orientation of a plane that is more nearly parallel to plane $\Pi$ than the $X,Y$ plane is, you may want to use more than one point to decide the angle of your plane. There are infinitely many ways to rotate the $X,Y$ plane around the origin so that the rotated plane passes through your given point $P.$ In fact, for each of these rotations there is another rotation that produces a plane through $P$ perpendicular to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.-Look at your first figure. You have
$$(|\vec v|\cos \alpha)^2=(|\vec v|\cos \theta_x)^2+(|\vec v|\cos \theta_y)^2$$ so you have

$$\cos^2(\alpha)=
\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)^2$$

$$\cos(\alpha)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$